# Selenium Python does not send.keys full text

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am writing one selenium python program to automate some stuff on slack...

So I need to read all IDs from a file and then append some prefix and suffix to that id and type it in text box on that page one one one.

What I tried is:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='textbox']")
with open('c:/ab/ids.txt') as in_file:
    for ids in in_file:
        time.sleep(3)
        elem.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(str("techie add"+" "+ids+" "+"demo"))
        time.sleep(3)
```

But when I run this

It typing like below
for example

```
techie add ABCD1
demo
techie add ABCD2
demo
techie add ABCD3
demo
techie add ABCD4
```

Contents of that ID file is:

```
ABCD1
ABCD2
ABCD3
ABCD4
```

Expected output(send key) --

```
techie add ABCD1 demo
techie add ABCD2 demo
techie add ABCD3 demo
techie add ABCD4 demo
```

any idea how to achieve this ? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that `ids` has a `\n` character in it, and by concatenating `ids + "demo"`, you might be adding that newline character, which would produce the output you are seeing.

I would recommend running a `.rstrip()` against `ids` to remove any trailing newline and see if that helps:

```
   for ids in in_file:
        time.sleep(3)
        elem.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(str("techie add"+" "+ids.rstrip()+" "+"demo"))
        time.sleep(3)
```

`.rstrip()` will strip out the newline characters and any other whitespace, as well. You can see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).